# Using VBA User Form to filter a pivot table (esp. in ways the Report Filter and Slicers can't)

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, created manually.  There are ways users need to be able to filter it which can't be done through Report Filters or Slicers, so I thought VBA would be the way to go.  I've built a skeletal user form, and am now at the tricky stage of writing the code behind it.

I'm trying to use the PivotFilters function, but this isn't working.  I will admit that I am an utter novice at VBA, so it may be a simple error I've made, or perhaps PivotFilters aren't the right tool for the job?  Here is an example:

```
'ok button - this is the big one, telling the button what to do with the selected options!

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'targeting our familiar pivot table

Dim pvt As PivotTable
Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

'Whether to filter out low sample size brands
Dim pvtFieldSasz As PivotField
Set pvtFieldSasz = pvt.PivotFields("SampleSize")

If OptionButton1 = True Then

pvt.pvtFieldSasz.PivotFilters.ClearAllFilters
pvt.pvtFieldSasz.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="Reliable Sample"

End If





End
```

The above example *is* something that can be done with Report Filters or Slicers, but I wanted to put all the relevant options in the user form, to make it a one-stop-shop for the user.

The error message I get is "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support the property or method".

I haven't moved on to the trickier ones yet, as I want to master the basics. As an example of what I'd like to achieve in a different filter:

The filter would refer to one of three separate columns, depending on the option selected by the user.  The user would have three option buttons, of which they can only select one at a time.  If they select OptionButton1, I would like the pivot table to be filtered on field X = 1.  If they select OptionButton2, it should filter on Field Y = 1.  OptionButton3 corresponds to Field Z = 1.  None of these fields X, Y or Z will actually be displayed in the pivot table as a row or column, but they are part of the source data and are included in the selection behind the pivot table.

Thank you for your patience helping this stumbling novice - very grateful for any tips!

Comment: edited to add the error message

Comment: I found your issue and am writing an answer, but in the future, you should put the line that the error message is happening on in addition to what the error message is.

Comment: Good point, will do - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these 2 lines:

```
 pvt.pvtFieldSasz.PivotFilters.ClearAllFilters
 pvt.pvtFieldSasz.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="Reliable Sample"
```

First, `pvtFieldSasz` already represents the pivot field.  Trying to specify it with `pvt.pvtFieldSasz` won't work because `pvtFieldSasz` is not a property or method of the pivottable, `pvt`.  Instead, you should just use `pvtFieldSasz`.  This will also be a problem in the immediately following statement.

Second, the `ClearAllFilters` method does not apply to the `PivotFilters` Property of the pivotField.  Instead, it applies to the pivotField itself.

Combining these two issues for working code:

```
 pvtFieldSasz.ClearAllFilters
 pvtFieldSasz.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="Reliable Sample"
```

As a sidenote, I'd also specify the sheet instead of using `ActiveSheet` as `ActiveSheet` can have issue, so

```
 Set pvt = Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - following your suggestions has eliminated the error message, hurrah!  However, submitting my UserForm does not actually filter the pivot table.  I wondered whether this is because the fields I'm trying to filter on are not rows in the pivot, but Microsoft's documentation seems to say that even "hidden" fields (i.e. not used as "row, column, page or data" fields) belong to the PivotFields collection.  I've checked that the field names and values that I've given are valid and they do seem to be, so I'm a bit stuck...

Comment: Further to my comment above, I've posted my new question on an Excel forum and it looks like PivotFilters don't actually work on fields that are not  displayed in the pivot table.  Shame.  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1010679-visual-basic-applications-pivotfilters-no-effect-pivot-table-puzzled.html#post4851382

Comment: I would ask a new question about this if you need help with something else.  However, if you want to achieve this, I would recommend a "helper" column in your dataset.  Make the button change a hidden cell to some value, so OptionButton1 changes cell A1 in another sheet to "X".  Then in the "helper" column in your data do something like, `IF(Helper!$A$1 = "X", IF(FieldXColumn2="1", 1, 0), IF(Helper!$A$1 = "Y", IF(FieldYColumn2="1",1,0), ....))`  Then filter the PivotTable on your "helper" column.  Refresh the PivotTable after setting the hidden cell.

Comment: Ooh, interesting.  I'm now trying a slightly different way (details in the linked thread in my previous comment), but if that goes pear-shaped I'll have a go at your method.  Thanks!